# Execute SQL script after SSIS build or check-in

Tags: sql-server, tfs, ssis, msbuild, continuous-integration

I am trying to find a better way to test our SSIS application, which is used to load data from a file into SQL Server and validate the file data.

I have created a SQL script which can be run to insert 'bad' data into the database tables, and ensure that our validations are performing correctly.

The SQL script:
- loads 'bad' data
- executes the SSIS validations
- ensures the errors in the data were detected
- Outputs a PASS or FAIL
- Deletes the TEST data if passed

Is there anyway I can get this script to be run automatically somehow, for example after someone checks in some code? Should I add it as a stored proc?

I had a look at the Default template Build definition but I couldn't see how to run this SQL script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't appear that you can do it as part of a checkin based on my 2 minutes of searching.

- [How to modify the default Check-in Action in TFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62294/how-to-modify-the-defaul-check-in-action-in-tfs)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243849(VS.80).aspx
- [Can I modify the default Check-in Action in TFS 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566485/can-i-modify-the-default-check-in-action-in-tfs-2012) (pretty picture)
- http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/562994/Perform-a-custom-action-for-Check-in-event-in-Micr

Instead, you'll need to set up a build server to handle the action. Out of the box, MSBuild doesn't have the ability to run a SQL Script so you'll need to snag the [MSBuild Extension Pack](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/) and leverage SqlExecute

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181712.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181710(v=vs.90).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668755(v=vs.90).aspx
- http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.5.0/html/0d864b98-649a-5454-76ea-bd3069fde8bd.htm

Answer (score 1):

The wrong way to do this is using a build server. There are lots of parts to a continuous integration and a build server is really designed for compilation and validation that does not require an instance of your environment. There are two good practices that you can adopt:

1. Create a test harness that allows you to load a singe package from your SSIS scripts and test the inputs and outputs. Essentially unit tests. I did this for a customer a few years ago and it worked well.
2. Use a [release management tool to push out your packages](http://nakedalm.com/building-release-pipeline-release-management-visual-studio-2013/), the data, and everything else that you need. Release Management for Visual Studio can do this easily.

A rule of thumb that I always go buy is if I do not need an instance of anything but in memory objects then all I need is a build server. However if I need an instance of my app then I want to add release management tools to my continuous integration strategy.

Comment: Oh, forgot: You can use the TCM.exe command line tool to sync your tests with Test Cases in TFS so that you can pull back results and execute them remotely on an environment: http://nakedalm.com/execute-tests-release-management-visual-studio-2013/

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Server Agent to embed for example your SQL code and you can than run this job from your application.

Comment: anyway to do it as part of the Build process and TFS?  Like Continuous Integration?  So the Test is ran as part of a check in process to ensure nothing has changed?>