# SSIS File Connection to TFS file

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, ssis

I am building an SSIS package with links to .sql files which are managed by TFS. What is the proper way to link the file connection to the correct version of the .sql file as managed by TFS?

I've tried using an expression to set the file connection's ConnectionString property to "%USERPROFILE%\Source\Workspaces\foo\bar.sql" but execution fails in debug mode. I receive the following error:

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error
>   message: "Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\Common7\IDE\%USERPROFILE%\Source\Workspaces\foo\bar.sql'.".

I am running Visual Studio 2013 on Windows Server 2012.

My question is: why is the the ConnectionString property being interpreted incorrectly?

The bigger question is: What is the proper way to link a the SSIS solution to other files managed by TFS?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a File connection to link a the SSIS solution to other files. And try adding a variable to set the .sql file fold path (the absolute file path, in TFS it should be in workspace).

To Execute .SQL files by using SSIS Package, please refer to below article for details.

http://www.techbrothersit.com/2012/10/ssis-execute-sql-files-by-using-ssis.html

And, there is a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ev94tNska38) here, you can follow the video step by step to do that.

---

I test that, the .sql files can be only executed when build locally in VS.
But in TFS, MSBuild doesn't have the ability to run a SQL Script so you'll need to snag the MSBuild Extension Pack and leverage SqlExecute. Please reference this thread : [Execute SQL script after SSIS build or check-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23992656/execute-sql-script-after-ssis-build-or-check-in)

If you want to run the .sql files you can try [Run SQL Server Scripts Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ggarbuglia.runsqlserverscripts-task) extension.

[image]

Comment: I am trying to include the SQL files in the same version control as the associated Visual Studio solution. The problem is that if they're managed by TFS, the path to the SQL files will vary based on the workspace configuration, so the file path must be a variable. In my original question, you can see the path is not being parsed as expected.

Comment: @Alex What about specify the absolute path for the .sql file? Do you build that in local VS or in TFS? Could you lease provide the detail steps to reproduce the issue? Based on my test, we can execute the .sql script when build locally in VS. Have you tried the steps mentioned in the linked video tutorial, if not, you can try it.

Comment: Since the SQL files are managed by TFS, I can't use an absolute path as it can change based on where the user is keeping their local copy of the project. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Alex Have you tried to use the variable eg $(build.artifactstagingdirectory), %USERPROFILE% should not be identified in the build process.